# Script to set IP address connected to an interface to a shell variable

Tags: command-line, scripts, environment-variables

I want to write a script to set the IP address of the device connected to an interface like "eth0" to a variable.
I can get the IP address by this command:

```
arp -i eth0 -a
```

The output of above command is:

```
? (10.42.0.38) at b8:27:eb:07:5d:60 [ether] on eth0
```

I want to add a script to `.bashrc` file to set the IP address from output of above command to the variable `$RASPBERRY_IP` and use it in other script.
Any idea how to do that?

Comment: Well the ip itself is easy enough to extract with awk. Why do you need an intermediate script ? Why not just get ip directly into the second script ?

Comment: @Serg I don't have problem with getting the ip address directly into second script. The problem is that I'm still a beginner in shell scripts and `awk` command you mentioned. I need the script to extract the ip from output of `arp` command and use it in a script. Tnx.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`arp` manipulates the entries in the kernel ARP cache, you are probably going to get a lot of entries (depends on the size of the LAN). As you are only interested in the IP addresses you should use the `-n` option so that `arp` shows numeric addresses instead of hostnames first.

Also you will typically get a lot of IP addresses depending the size of your LAN, so you should probably use an array instead of a variable to store the IP addresses.

The following command takes the IP addresses out of the `arp` cache and put them in array `addrs` :

```
addrs=( $(arp -ni eth0 | grep -o '^[0-9][^ ]*') )
```

Here is an example :

```
$ addrs=( $(arp -ni eth0 | grep -o '^[0-9][^ ]*') )

$ echo "${addrs[0]}"  ## First IP
192.168.2.27

$ echo "${addrs[2]}"  ## Second IP
192.168.1.1

$ echo "${#addrs[@]}"  ## Number of IP addresses
37
```

You can use `sed` too :

```
addrs=( $(arp -ni eth0 | sed -nr 's/^([0-9][^ ]*).*/\1/p') )
```

The IP addresses will be shown in the first column, we are extracting the first column by `[0-9][^ ]*`. `^[0-9]` here is to ensure that the line starts with a numeric so the first line containing header is discarded from the output.

---

On a different note if you have only one entry you can save it in a variable instead :

```
addr="$(arp -ni eth0 | grep -o '^[0-9][^ ]*')"
```

Or

```
addr="$(arp -ni eth0 | sed -nr 's/^([0-9][^ ]*).*/\1/p')"
```

Comment: Enough, upvoted ;)

Comment: Good job , guys !

Answer (score 3):

Here is another idea using `awk`

```
arp -ni eth0 | awk 'NR>1 {print $1}'
```

*Example*

```
$ arp -ni eth0 | awk 'NR>1 {print $1}'
192.168.20.3
192.168.20.1
192.168.20.11
```

or with a variable

```
$ addresses=$(arp -ni eth0 | awk 'NR>1 {print $1}')
$ echo $addresses
192.168.20.3 192.168.20.1 192.168.20.11
```

---

To get a specific index without an array

```
$ arp -ni eth0 | awk -v idx=3 'NR>1 && NR==idx+1 {print $1}'
192.168.20.11
```

To get the maximum value for `idx`

```
arp -ni eth0 | awk 'NR>1 {idx_max++} END {print idx_max}'
```

*Example*

```
$ idx_max=$(arp -ni eth0 | awk 'NR>1 {idx_max++} END {print idx_max}')
$ echo $idx_max
3
```

Comment: Here you go.. :)

Comment: :D  **@heemayl**: You and **A.B.** are like children competing!  Still a tie!